# Find a 2D point in space based on angle and distance

Tags: c++, math, geometry

Ok.... so I made a quick diagram to sorta explain what I'm hoping to accomplish. Sadly math is not my forte and I'm hoping one of you wizards can give me the correct formulas :)  This is for a c++ program, but really I'm looking for the formulas rather than c++ code.

[image: Diagram]

Ok, now basically, the red circle is our 0,0 point, where I'm standing. The blue circle is 300 units above us and at what I would assume is a 0 degree's angle. I want to know, how I can find a find the x,y for a point in this chart using the angle of my choice as well as a certain distance of my choice.

I would want to know how to find the x,y of the green circle which is lets say 225 degrees and 500 units away.

So I assume I have to figure out a way to transpose a circle that is 500 units away from 0,0 at all points than pick a place on that circle based on the angle I want? But yeah no idea where to go from there.

Comment: The answer provided is good. Also your blue point is actually at (300,90°) in polar coordinate. The angle is mesured starting from the X axis in the positive direction. (if your Referential is direct)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A point on a plane can be expressed in two main mathematical representations, cartesian (thus `x,y`) and polar : using a distance from the center and an angle. Typically `r` and a greek letter, but let's use `w`.

### Definitions

Under common conventions, r is the distance from the center (0,0) to your point, and
angles are measured going counterclockwise (for positive values, clockwise for negative), with the 0 being the horizontal on the right hand side.

### Remarks

Note a few things about angles in polar representations :

- angles can be expressed with radians as well, with π being the same angle as 180°, thus π/2 90° and so on. π=3.14 (approx.) is defined by 2π=the perimeter of a circle of radius 1.
- angles can be represented modulo a full circle. A full circle is either 2π or 360°, thus +90° is the same as -270°, and +180° and -180° are the same, as well as 3π/4 and -5π/4, 2π and 0, 360° and 0°, etc. You can consider angles between [-π,π] (that is [-180,180]) or [0,2π] (i.e. [0,360]), or not restrain them at all, it doesn't matter.
- when your point is in the center (r=0) then the angle w is not really defined.
- r is by definition always positive. If r is negative, you can change its sign and add half a turn (π or 180°) to get coordinates for the same point.

### Points on your graph

- red : x=0, y=0 or r=0 w= any value
- blue : x=0, y=300 or r=300 and w=90°
- green : x=-400, y=-400 or r=-565 and w=225° (approximate values, I didn't do the actual measurements)

Note that for the blue point you can have w=-270°, and for the green w=-135°, etc.

### Going from one representation to the other

Finally, you need trigonometry formulas to go back and forth between representations. The easier transformation is from polar to cartesian :

```
x=r*cos(w)
y=r*sin(w)
```

Since cos²+sin²=1, pythagoras, and so on, you can see that `x² + y² = r²cos²(w) + r²sin²(w) = r²`, thus to get r, use :

```
r=sqrt(x²+y²)
```

And finally to get the angle, we use `cos/sin = tan` where tan is another trigonometry function. From `y/x = r sin(w) / (r cos(w)) = tan(w)`, you get :

```
w = arctan(y/x) [mod π]
```

tan is a function modulo π, instead of 2π. arctan simply means the inverse of the function tan, and is sometimes written tan^-1 or atan.

By inverting the tangent, you get a result betweeen -π/2 and π/2 (or -90° and 90°) : you need to eventually add π to your result. This is done for angles between [π/2,π] and [-π,π/2] ([90,180] and [-180,-90]). These values are caracterized by the sign of the cos : since `x = r cos(w)` you know x is negative on all these angles. Try looking where these angles are on your graph, it's really straightforward. Thus :

```
w = arctan(y/x) + (π if x < 0)
```

Finally, you can not divide by x if it is 0. In that corner case, you have

- if y > 0, `w = π/2`
- if y < 0, `w = -π/2`

Answer (score 2):

What is seems is that given polar coordinates, you want to obtain Cartesian coordinates from this. It's some simple mathematics and should be easy to do.

to convert polar(r, O) coordinates to cartesian(x, y) coordinates

`x = r * cos(O)`

`y = r * sin(O)`

where `O` is **theta**, not zero

reference: http://www.mathsisfun.com/polar-cartesian-coordinates.html